# Can't find Android SDK for Eclipse with ADT plugin

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-studio, adt

I really need to setup Android development with eclipse (ADT plugin) just after format my laptop...

I know everywhere suggest to migrate to Android Studio but really NOT want to do it until next release may be next month.

It always brings to [THIS PAGE](http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html) and forcing to install android studio which is NOT what I am looking for at the moment.

Also I find this [LINK](https://stuff.mit.edu/afs/sipb/project/android/docs/sdk/installing/installing-adt.html) that provides ADT plugin installation guide but after successfully install ADT plugin it's not downloading and install SDK as earlier....

Would be grateful if anyone can guide me just to set up eclipse for Android development until migrate to Android Studio in a convenient time. Thanks

Comment: Don't know why the down vote. If you try to set up eclipse for android from the beginning you will find the problem. Looks like they completely stopped support for eclipse but definitely there should be a way to do it until people migrate (leave old environment without further improvements)...

Comment: `it's not downloading and install SDK as earlier.` This happens because unfortunately Google totally dropped the support for Eclipse and the ADT. My advice: **don't format** your PCs. The only solution you can **hope** to work around is to **copy** the installation from another PC. And then spend a lot of time in trying to fix all the paths.

Answer (score 2):

I don't have first-hand experience with this, but if your ADT plugin cannot install Android SDK anymore, you can try a workaround: install AndroidStudio, let it install the SDK, and let ADT look at the same directory. I did this a number of times in the opposite direction (starting with working Eclipse/ADT, and reusing same SDK from AS).

Comment: Will test this way and post the result. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I did the same as you, I downloaded a "stand alone" version of ADT and dowloaded every Android version that I wanted to work with.

I downloaded Eclipse Mars, opened it, then I went in the Market Place (in Tools if I remember correctly) and looked for "Android". I then downloaded the ADT (Android Developer Tool) which you can also find on this page : http://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/android-development-tools-eclipse

Comment: I didn't find this one. Will give it ago and post the results. Thanks

Comment: You can also directly install the plugin from google website http://dl.google.com/android/ADT-22.6.3.zip (you will have to copy paste the files in the plugin folder, somewhere in your eclipse folder but i dont know where exactly ;) ! Keep us up to date :)

Answer (score 0):

to clarify, the problem is ADT doesnt install the sdk folder anymore, and also, doesnt support any of the sdk manager above their last version... you can try to look up a sdk manager version that suits ADT, but good look with that. The only way to use eclipse with android sdk is to copy another eclipse well configured with de sdk manager folder, from another pc